# ¿Cómo convertir XML a Json?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Quiera saber si hay alguna manera de convertir un `xml` a `json` usando Javascript.

Comment: Y qué has investigado? porque si no cualquiera te puede responder que la manera es programando y transformando el árbol del dom elemento a elemento y la respuesta sería correcta, solo especifica un poco mejor tu pregunta por favor :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la librería [jsonxml](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/) de Stefan Goessner (Hay un buen [artículo](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html?page=1) en inglés que explica la herramienta a detalle).

Uso

```
function xml2json(xml,  // xml define un documento o elemento xml
                  tab)  // tab es usado para formato 
                        // se omite para usar "" 
                        // regresa una cadena JSON 

function json2xml(obj,  // objeto javascript 
                  tab)  // tab es usado para formato  
                        // se omite para usar "" 
                        // regresa una cadena XML
```

Aquí hay algunos [ejemplos de resultados](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/xmljson_test.html).

La herramienta incluye tanto `xml` a `json`, como `json` a `xml`.

*Nota:*

Para agregar archivos `Javascript` a proyectos `ASP` puedes checar este [buen tutorial](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/tutorial-asp-net-ejecutar-codigo-javascript-en-aspnet/) o simplemente en la carpeta de `Scripts` -> Agregar -> Elemento existente y seleccionar el archivo `.js` deseado.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en `Visual Studio` supongo que lo tengo que incluir la librería primero, y si así fuera como lo meto la librería al proyecto ?

Comment: @JoséGregorioCalderón Asi es la que tu buscas es [esta] (ya que los archivos vienen por separado )[http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/xml2json.js]

Comment: Lo checare gracias.

Answer (score 0):

siempre esta la opción de hacerlo a pie, pero para que reinventar la rueda.

Una busqueda rápida arroja varios resultados interesantes:

- El anteriormente ya mencionado jsonxml de Stefan Goessner.
- [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js) - XML a JSON y de vuelta para JavaScript.
- [xmlToJSON](https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON) - Utilidad sencilla para convertir xml en JSON.

Ahora sería que revises cual te sirve mejor. Aquí mismo te podríamos ayudar a usar una u otra dependiendo de tus necesidades.